# Google Drive Picker - Developer Key is Invalid Error

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-picker

I started to learn Google Drive Picker API and started with my `localhost` (I have created my client id and browser key for the domain `http://localhost/` and my files locations are localhost/ch1.html etc.

Here's the script I wrote in the body part of my document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
<script>
    function onApiLoad(){
        gapi.load('auth',{'callback':onAuthApiLoad}); 
        gapi.load('picker'); 
    }
    function onAuthApiLoad(){
        window.gapi.auth.authorize({
            'client_id':'545195528713-tihc7u0hp9ihta5mrm4l0eon16fpjogi.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            'scope':['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
        },handleAuthResult);
    } 
    var oauthToken;
    function handleAuthResult(authResult){
        if(authResult && !authResult.error){
            oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
            createPicker();
        }
    }
    function createPicker(){    
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
            .addView(new google.picker.DocsView())                
            .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
            .setDeveloperKey('AIzaSyB3I3JOepScrZgySA9tBWL9pXAUaLJ-NFg')
            .build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
    }
</script>
```

But when I run the doc it shows nothing. Is it like I can't use the drive api on `localhost` or I will have to use some button to call it or something like that please help.

Tested Example -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Picker Example</title>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
<script>
    function onApiLoad(){
        gapi.load('auth',{'callback':onAuthApiLoad}); 
        gapi.load('picker'); 
    }
    function onAuthApiLoad(){
        window.gapi.auth.authorize({
            'client_id':'545195528713-tihc7u0hp9ihta5mrm4l0eon16fpjogi.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            'scope':['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
        },handleAuthResult);
    } 
    var oauthToken;
    function handleAuthResult(authResult){
        if(authResult && !authResult.error){
            oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
            createPicker();
        }
    }
    function createPicker(){    
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
            .addView(new google.picker.DocsView())                
            .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
            .setDeveloperKey('AIzaSyC4N7lg1vN6YrxcD5DDt_Iu0GXsF3QGFDU')
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
    }

    function pickerCallback(data) {
        var url = 'nothing';
        if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
          var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
          url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
        }
        var message = 'You picked: ' + url;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;
      }
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: google-project-keys][image: terminal-chrome][image: list of image api's enabled]

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser debug console?

Comment: Do you enable `Google Picker API`?

Comment: Yes @Fresh I got one error in the console, i attached a picture to show more about it. please check and yes user2511140 i did enable the google picker api please check the edit once and see if i am using the wrong api key or something like that as it is giving me that error

Comment: Note, with the new interface the link to enable the Picker API is not immediately obvious. There's a search box under API Manager > Overview > Google API's. Type "picker " into the box and it will show up. I was confused that I couldn't find it before I did that.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You must enable picker api: 
go https://console.developers.google.com/  select your project then click `APIs & auth` find `Google Picker API` and enable it.
I add `.setCallback(pickerCallback)` to `createPicker` function and add new function (`pickerCallback`)
complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Picker Example</title>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
<script>
    function onApiLoad(){
        gapi.load('auth',{'callback':onAuthApiLoad}); 
        gapi.load('picker'); 
    }
    function onAuthApiLoad(){
        window.gapi.auth.authorize({
            'client_id':'545195528713-tihc7u0hp9ihta5mrm4l0eon16fpjogi.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            'scope':['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
        },handleAuthResult);
    } 
    var oauthToken;
    function handleAuthResult(authResult){
        if(authResult && !authResult.error){
            oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
            createPicker();
        }
    }
    function createPicker(){    
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
            .addView(new google.picker.DocsView())                
            .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
            .setDeveloperKey('AIzaSyB3I3JOepScrZgySA9tBWL9pXAUaLJ-NFg')
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
    }

    function pickerCallback(data) {
        var url = 'nothing';
        if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
          var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
          url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
        }
        var message = 'You picked: ' + url;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;
      }
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I copied this code and tried it but it says invalid api developer key thats why i am attaching an image with my credentials so that you can verify if i am using the correct key or not. and also i am getting an error in console saying ---- "Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://docs.google.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://localhost')."

Comment: I am making an edit in the question with the attached images please have a look

Comment: above code works with my api key. problem:Your drive api key status is inactive.active it or create new key (select server or browser key)

Comment: I thought that inactive status is for the older key that i had. isn't that the case??? Or

Comment: Okay i created a new browser key and server key both with the key values and got the error again. I think i am not able to understand about the allowed referrals and the origins provided in the client id and the developer key that might be creating a problem. can you tell your allowed origins and redirect urls for localhost

Comment: use my clinetId and Api key place your file in root(`http://localhost/picker.html`) if this works problem in your key and origins else problem in local server.my clinetId: `844456571877-216ioacquegru1n994c5tk96adtgsq2v.apps.googleusercontent.com`  api key: `AIzaSyBbhzarsOFCrBzNSVo-_XOZ0DUlNbWJ6oA`

Comment: Okay yeah it seems that there is problem with my origins only coz your  keys work and i don't get an error. can you please tell me what origins and redirect urls you have used or a screenshot of it would do. Thank you in advance

Comment: thanks for accept answer. i add images to my answer.Redirect URIs is `http://localhost/` please test code with your own key on another server if not work use another google account.

Comment: Okay yeah, it worked when i used the server key previously i added only my local ip instead of allowing all ip's i think that was the problem

Answer (score 37):

I don't know if Google has changed the API's since the accepted answer, but today, in January 2015, this worked for me, where the above answers didn't:

According to the Credentials page:

> Public API access
>
> Use of this key does not require any user action or consent, does not grant access to any account information, and is not used for authorization.

Elsewhere I read that the API/Developer/Browser key is not needed if oAuthToken is used. So, I amended the above code, by simply losing the line:

```
.setDeveloperKey('AIzaSyB3I3JOepScrZgySA9tBWL9pXAUaLJ-NFg')
```

For completeness, here's the full amended code, hope it works for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Picker Example</title>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
        <script>
            function onApiLoad() {
                gapi.load('auth', { 'callback': onAuthApiLoad });
                gapi.load('picker');
            }
            function onAuthApiLoad() {
                window.gapi.auth.authorize({
                    'client_id': '545195528713-tihc7u0hp9ihta5mrm4l0eon16fpjogi.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                    'scope': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
                }, handleAuthResult);
            }
            var oauthToken;
            function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
                if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                    oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
                    createPicker();
                }
            }
            function createPicker() {
                var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                    //.addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
                    .addView(new google.picker.DocsView())
                    .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
                    //.setDeveloperKey('AIzaSyDPs9U-dgOC9h1jRFNwOwhRtARCph8_3HM')
                    .setCallback(pickerCallback)
                    .build();
                picker.setVisible(true);
            }

            function pickerCallback(data) {
                var url = 'nothing';
                if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
                    var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
                    url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
                }
                var message = 'You picked: ' + url;
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;
            }
        </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was facing this issue on Brave browser, and as mentioned here, removing the `setDeveloperKey` line fixed it. However, Google Chrome didn't need this change and was working fine without it and Google's documentation doesn't have anything about the developer key being optional. (https://developers.google.com/picker/docs)

Comment: For me removing `setDeveloperKey` eliminated baffling "500" errors creating the Google Picker.

Answer (score 1):

Check that popups aren't being blocked
(there should be a popup allowing you to authorise the client app)

Answer (score 1):

Create and use **API key for Browser application** instead of API key for Server application as it is done in the images provided by you. That will solve the problem.

Thanks.