# Google Picker API developerkey

Tags: google-api

I am trying to use the [Google Picker API](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/). But i am having trouble locating the Developer Key.

I have created my project and set up OAuth. i Have the following:-

```
Client ID      123xyz.apps.googleusercontent.com
Email address  987abc@developer.gserviceaccount.com
Client secret  1234-56789
```

However the Google Picker script requires the following:-

```
// The API developer key obtained from the Google Developers Console.
var developerKey = '';

// The Client ID obtained from the Google Developers Console.
var clientId = '987abc@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
```

Could someone please tell me where i can find my Developer Key?

I have looked all through my Developer Console but cannot find it anywhere!!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a `developer key` in the code but is referred to as an `API key` on the Google Developer console.

You have to go to the [Google Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com), select your project, then click the red button called `Create New Key` and walk through the steps specific to your situation.

You may also find [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435410/google-drive-picker-api) relevant either now or if you run into another question about the picker.

Comment: Thank-you! It was under `my-project->Apis & auth->Credentials` in the `Public API access` section labelled `API Key`. Cheers, Xenocideae!