# Google drive picker error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-api, google-picker

I am getting following error while accessing google drive picker, however the picker shows up properly without any error.

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://docs.google.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://localhost').

Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'https://docs.google.com/picker?protocol=gadgets&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalho…%3Atrue%7D))&rpctoken=e2x1eop3h1rr&rpcService=2qeo0ns6gu13&thirdParty=true': 'ALLOW-FROM http://localhost' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored.
```

PSB the screenshot from my developer console

http://screencloud.net/v/6431

Also I have referred to this question [Google Drive Picker - Developer Key is Invalid Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435410/google-drive-picker-developer-key-is-invalid-error) but I think there has been some changes in google api so this thing is not working.

Code snippet -

```
var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                             .setLocale(lkGoogleSettings.locale)
                             .setOAuthToken(accessToken)
                             .setCallback(pickerResponse)
                             .setOrigin(lkGoogleSettings.origin);
```

Thanks

Comment: `http://localhost' is not a recognized directive`.
Perhaps Google API expects a port number, as in `http://localhost:80`?

Comment: FWIW this only happens in Chrome.  The 2nd issue is reported as a bug they're not planning to fix. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=511521

Comment: I think google file picker works only in live server, you need to host it

Comment: Its working Paresh and the error comes only in chrome

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I ran into the same issue in the Android build of my ionic application.

Comment: Nope, its an existing bug in their api...No solution

Answer (score 9):

As some of the commentators have mentioned, the `X-Frame-Option` error is known bug in `Chrome`. You can see a long discussion about it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-picker-api/_wF1O_3j7ZE/yfHhQTz2DPwJ).

Now, for the real problem: `origin matching`. Google Drive does not play nice with localhost, with or without port, regardless of whether you add it to your origins in your permissions for your client id.

There is, however, hope. If you set up a domain in your hostfile to point to localhost, you can then add the domain to your origin in your Google App console, and everything works as expected!

I do this all the time in order to test my applications. For example:

1. add `dev.mysite.com` to your `hostfile` (/etc/hosts in *Mac*).
2. Replicate the domain in your permissions for your picker app in the `Google App Console`, and you should be good to go.
3. Start your site using `dev.mysite.com:80`* and Drive Picker should now function correctly.

***Note:** you must serve on port 80. Google does not play nice with ports at all, so when you go to your site, the address must be `dev.mysite.com` with no port.

Comment: Any reason for the down vote? I do not believe a cosmetic edit should be enough to down vote a correct answer with an actual solution.