# Google Drive File Picker random sign-in error

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Occasionally (sporadically) when the Google Drive file picker is triggered in our app by a properly authenticated user, the picker fails with a message that they need to sign-in to Google (note old Google logo) - clicking this message's Google sign-in button gives the error message `API Developer key is invalid`.

We removed the API Developer key from the picker call and now the error message after sign-in reads- `Details:
The feature you requested is currently unavailable. Please try again later.`

Usually the picker works after refreshing the page.

Is this a known bug for the Google Drive picker or is there a workaround?

[Google Drive Picker Sign-in error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wxaG.png)

[Google Drive Picker developer key error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZiVl.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We ended up writing our own drive picker and not using Google's picker at all.

Comment: Did you open source it? I want to check it out.

Comment: Sorry - we never open sourced that ... we moved on to other more pressing projects.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you use Browser key not Server key and try to verify if you follow the steps here in [Register your Project](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#appreg). It will give you step by step procedure on how to use API key with your project. It also have code example for you to follow.

I also see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435410/google-drive-picker-developer-key-is-invalid-error) related to your problem. Solutions here is to add `.setCallback(pickerCallback)` to `createPicker` function and add new function `(pickerCallback)`. I hope it can help you.

Comment: Picker API was enabled and project registered and we had already done the setCallback etc. The picker works 99% of the time.